# why not preorder recursive logic?

Tags: binary-tree, recursive-datastructures

hey guys I wrote this program to left clone a tree i.e every node adds a clone of itself to its left branch and moves the remaining branches down the left, but when I applied the recursive logic in preorder it did not work but when written in postorder it did can you please tell me why that is, thanks I advance.

why this:

```
static void leftCloned(Node root){
        if(root == null ){
            return ;
        }
        leftCloned(root.left);
        leftCloned(root.right);
        Node clone = new Node(root.data);
        clone.left = root.left;
        root.left = clone;
    }
```

why not this:

```
static void leftCloned(Node root){
            if(root == null ){
                return ;
            }
            Node clone = new Node(root.data);
            clone.left = root.left;
            root.left = clone;
            leftCloned(root.left);
            leftCloned(root.right);
        }
```

Comment: How can a node object be equated to NULL? Also new operator returns a pointer to node object allocated in heap.

Comment: @soubhisken if this is Java, every object is a reference, and a null reference is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @soubhiksen both the codes look same to me. What's the difference?

Comment: Your second version is an infinite recursion, because you immediately call `leftCloned()` on the newly cloned node.

Comment: @AtharvaSharma I have edited it,  sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @jasonharper got it thanks.